# How to click on a input button in a non static page (webbrowser c#)?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, non-static

I'm trying to click on a input button on a page in my webbrowser form, but InvokeMember event is not working, I researched, and read that the InvokeMember only works on static page, but the page, that I'm trying to automate the click, is not static , I do not find a way to click the input of a non-static page.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

I've tried:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginBtn").InvokeMember("Click");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginBtn").RaiseEvent("onclick");
```

**Tanks for the help, I found the answer**
The page was anti-robot and does not allow a very quick click, then placing a

```
 Thread.sleep (1000);
```

tricked the the page and allowed the automation login.

Comment: If the button is a submit button then just submit() the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a login page for a web application, and I am using the validate() method with my button.onclick function.

```
<input type="button" id="commit" value="Sign in" onclick=" validate() ">`
```